# Linux fails with starting on a dualboot system after Windows update

Tags: linux, kernel, boot

I have Windows 7 and Kali Linux on my computer, normally I don't use windows anymore. But today I started windows and it updated itself. I am writing my thesis and all my stuff is in Linux so I really need to get it started my deadline is near.

In the grub bootloader I choosed Lali Linux, and in the next windows it says

```
early console in decompress_kernel
Decompressing Linux.... Parsing ELF.... done.
Booting the kernel.
```

Then nothing happens.
What can I do? I really need my stuff and can't just format the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Kali Linux install uses ext4 (or an older version, which will work even better), you may also be interested in installing ext4 drivers for your windows 7 installation, so you can access your files from within windows. I've used them with reasonable success  (I run Windows 7 and Arch Linux). To be safe I would disable writing the your ext4 partition, only enable reading (which should be enough to recover your thesis).

Link: http://www.ext2fsd.com/

Answer (score 1):

use a live-cd (ubuntu/fedora) and acess your Linux partitions, copy the files/data from there to your windows partitions.

First priority is to save the Data. copy to an external disk/usb pendrive, then Later fix the grub issue with grub restore/rescue process.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer... i really dont know what happened. I tried to boot live and got a failure, that some flags are set wrong, which i didnt change in the last months. Then I started again and was too late to access the boot menu, so Linux started and now it works as usual. I dont understand why it failed all the times I tried before, neither why it works now :D but i am so happy that I have my stuff back without investing lots of time^^ .